# Significance of an interval for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

## Question

Find all the solutions for the equation 
$$y'(x)+y(x)=\int_0^x y(t) dt$$
defined on $[0,1]$.

## Attempt

I have calculated the complete solution as 
$$y(x)=Ae^{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}x}+Be^{\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}x}$$
However, I cannot figure out what to do with the provided interval since the equation make sense for all values of $x$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Can somebody explain what the question intends me to do with the interval?

## Edit

As seen by answers below I have realised the interval acts provides the initial. Proceeding under the provided information, I got the answer as follows

$$y'(0)=-y(0)$$
$$y(0)= Ae^{0}+Be^{0}=A+B$$

$$y'(0)= \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}Ae^{0}+\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}Be^{0}= \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}A+\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}B$$

$$-\left( \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}A+\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}B \right)=A+B$$

$$\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}A+\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}B =A+B$$

$$\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}A=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}B $$
$$\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}A=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}B $$
$$A=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{1+\sqrt5}B $$

Inputting this in the final equation

$$y(x)=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{1+\sqrt5}Be^{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}x}+Be^{\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}x} = B\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{1+\sqrt5}e^{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}x}+e^{\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}x} \right)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The interval seems irrelevant, but in differentiating you "destroyed" the information $y(0)+y'(0)=0$ which you need to recover.

Comment: I am getting infinitely many possible values of A and B (1 equation 2 variables). Is that consistent with the question?

Comment: $$\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}A=\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}B$$ You sure about this ?$$ You sure about this ?

Comment: Yes, why? Is it wrong?

Comment: It seems there is a sign mistake for B  $$-\frac 12 B +B =\frac B2$$ should be positive

Comment: Is the final solution all correct now?

Comment: lol it's better now yes +1 for your efforts

Comment: Thank you very much @Isham

Comment: The interval is only relevant to the initial condition in that $x=0$ is in it, so that the condition $\int_0^0 y(x) dx=0$ needs to be retained after differentiation. But if $0$ were not in it then the problem would be very different, because you would need information about $y$ in a neighborhood of zero to compute the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Let $Y(x)=\int_0^x y(t) dt$, then $Y(0)=0$ (see Ian's comment!) and 
$$Y''(x)+Y'(x)=y'(x)+y(x)=\int_0^x y(t) dt=Y(x)$$
which is a linear differential equation whose general solution over $\mathbb{R}$ (not just on the interval $[0,1]$) is the one you have already found :
$$Y(x)=ae^{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}x}+be^{\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}x}$$
In order to have $Y(0)=0$ we need that $a=-b$ and
$$y(x)=Y'(x)=a\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}e^{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}x}+a\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}e^{\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}x}$$
or
$$y(x)=Ae^{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}x}+Be^{\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}x}\quad \text{with $A=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}B$}.$$

Comment: So basically the interval provides me the initial condition?

Comment: I am getting infinitely many possible values of A and B (1 equation 2 variables). Is that consistent with the question?

Comment: @mathnoob123 You are right! I added a reference to his comment.

Comment: Yes there are infinite solutions all proportional to $e^{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}x}-e^{\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}x}$. In fact you can see directy that if $y(x)$ is a solution then also $Cy(x)$ is a solution for any $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am getting $\frac{\sqrt5}{2}A =\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}B$

Comment: I mean $Y(x)=A(e^{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}x}-e^{\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}x})$. Then $y(x)=Y'(x)$.

Comment: Your relation suggests that $A=-B$ which is not the same as my previous comment. Am I doing a mistake or are they both equivalent? If yes, please explain how?

Comment: Can you check my edit?

Comment: It should be $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}A =\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}B$